# special character was lost when saving excel into csv file

Tags: windows, excel, csv, character-encoding, ms-office

I have an Excel file including latin character, which is shown as follows:

```
abcón
```

After saving it into a csv file, the latin character was lost

```
abc??n
```

What causes this problem and how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: I've just tried this with your exact text and could not reproduce the problem...

Comment: Yes, I tried this on one another computer, it works fine. I am not sure why it happens on my labtop. Is there any mechanism to tune the encoding of a csv file in a computer. Looks like it is machine-dependent.

Comment: Perhaps check your two computers' regional settings to see if there are any differences.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the ó you're using in the excel file isn't supported in ascii text.  There are a couple different symbols that look almost if not entirely identical.  From the Insert->Symbol character map, `00F3` is supported and is from the latin extended alphabet.  However, `1F79` from the greek extended alphabet is not supported and from my casual inspection is identical.  Try replacing the char in question with the char from the char map.

Alternatively, you can use Alt-Codes and use `0243` for the char which should work.